# JSON iPhone - Help

Tags: json, iphone

I can get the following JSON data back from the web services.

**Questions**:

1. Is the correct format for JSON that should return?
2. I have no idea to get back those data on xcode?

Anyone could give me hand?

Thanks a lot.

http://192.168.11.6/specificRegion.php?region_ID=011

```
[{"idReference_no":"R00008","Region_ID":"011","HouseMall_Name_In_Chinese":"A","Rental_Month":"0","Rental_Hour":"0","Rental_Fee_Month":"0.00","Rental_Fee_Hour":"0.00"}, {"idReference_no":"R00009","Region_ID":"011","HouseMall_Name_In_Chinese":"B","Rental_Month":"0","Rental_Hour":"0","Rental_Fee_Month":"0.00","Rental_Fee_Hour":"0.00"}, {"idReference_no":"R00010","Region_ID":"011","HouseMall_Name_In_Chinese":"C","Rental_Month":"0","Rental_Hour":"0","Rental_Fee_Month":"0.00","Rental_Fee_Hour":"0.00"}, {"idReference_no":"R00011","Region_ID":"011","HouseMall_Name_In_Chinese":"D","Rental_Month":"0","Rental_Hour":"0","Rental_Fee_Month":"0.00","Rental_Fee_Hour":"0.00"}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parsing JSON object in iPhone SDK (XCode) using JSON-Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165290/how-to-parsing-json-object-in-iphone-sdk-xcode-using-json-framework)

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: you can always check for the validity of a json object at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/). Also check out the [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) chrome extension if you're a chrome user. For using JSON in xcode projects, refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165290/how-to-parsing-json-object-in-iphone-sdk-xcode-using-json-framework).

Comment: Hi, Very strange !
I paste the JSON string on the JSON Validator and it said: 'Invalid JSON : error in line 1.....'. At the first line and first characters : '[' , I found there is some hidden code that invisible but if I click right arraow and left arrrow and delete it, it will be ok. It seems delete a hidden code... Why there is hidden code?? which is generated from php...

Comment: Could be BOM... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740973/why-doesnt-jquery-parsejson-work-on-all-servers